Reducedness of blowup implies reducedness of original scheme?
Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $X'\to X$ be a birational morphism by blowing up an ideal of $X$.   Suppose $X'$ is reduced (or even smooth). Is it possible to conclude that $X$ is reduced as well?

Consider for example the blowup of the spectrum of $k[t]/t^2$ at the maximal ideal.
